# Cannot find path when using remove-item cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I wrote out a simple PowerShell script that backs up a directory to `C:\` and then deletes any of the backup folders when its age = X days.

For some reason, when I use the `Remove-Item` cmdlet I'm getting a `Remove-Item: Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\ [Sub-Folder name]' because it does not exist` error.

Below is the snippet:

```
    $TargetFolder = "C:\Folder\"
    $Folders = get-childitem -path $TargetFolder
    foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
    {
      remove-item $Folder -recurse -force
    }
```

Within the `$TargetFolder = "C:\Folder\"`, there are a few sub-folders. 
Examples: `C:\Folder\SubfolderA`, `C:\Folder\SubfolderB`, etc.

When I do a `Write-Host` for `$Folder` it lists `SubFolderA`, `SubFolderB`, etc, correctly so I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting a `Cannot find path` error.

Comment: so why are you doing it like that? why not just  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $targetfolder?

Comment: I didn't want to delete all the contents in $TargetFolder. I only wanted to delete the backup folders that have reached a specific age. Here's the script. @4c74356b41 

`code
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "5"
$TargetFolder = "C:\Folder\"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

$Folders = get-childitem -path $TargetFolder | 
Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | 
Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} 

    foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
    {
     Remove-Item -path $Folder -Recurse -Force 
    }
`code`

Comment: ok, first of all you would want to use get-childitem -directory, to avoid another pipe. also there's no sense in calling $now.adddays, call (Get-Date).AddDays directly. Also, try to use $folder.fullname in the remove-item

Comment: You should [edit your code into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40491642/edit). IMO the code sample you have provided only tells half the story of what you want to do and also, you might get better help if you show the whole picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you want to do this on the basis of the directory LastWriteTime, but you did not mention -Directory on Get-ChildItem.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

$TargetFolder = "C:\Users\lit\Documents"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetFolder -Directory
$Days = 80

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    if ($Folder.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)) {
        Write-Verbose "Deleting directory $($Folder.FullName)"
        Remove-Item -WhatIf "$($Folder.FullName)" -Recurse -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating; actually, PowerShell variables generally don't need double-quoting as arguments (unless they're to be _embedded_ in  a double-quoted string), even if they contain spaces. Thus, `Remove-Item $Folder.FullName` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

To ensure that `Remove-Item` correctly identifies a directory object as returned by `Get-ChildItem` (an instance of type `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`):

- When passing the object **as a *parameter*** value (argument), in *Windows PowerShell* (no longer in PowerShell *Core*) you ***must* use `.FullName`** for the command to work *reliably*:

  ```
  Remove-Item -LiteralPath $Folder.FullName ... # !! Note the need for .FullName
  ```

<sup>`-LiteralPath` is not strictly needed, but is the more robust choice, given that `Remove-Item $Folder.FullName` implicitly binds to the `-Path` parameter instead, which interprets its argument as a *wildcard expression*; often this will make no difference, but it *can*.</sup>

- When using the ***pipeline***, you can **pass the objects *as-is***.

  ```
  Get-ChildItem -Directory | Remove-Item ...
  ```

The surprising need to use `.FullName` is the result of a design quirk; the resulting behavior and its implications are discussed below; a fix has been proposed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057).

---

[Liturgist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493280/45375) and [AJK's helfpul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492490/45375) contain complementary pieces of the solution (Liturgist's answer has since been amended to provide a complete solution):

- To limit what `Get-ChildItem` returns to *directories* (folders), you must use `-Directory` (PSv3+).
- To unambiguously identify a filesystem object when passing it to `Remove-Object` *as a parameter* that is converted to a *string*, its *full path* must be specified.

  - Note: The **situational filename-only stringification** described below **affects only *Windows PowerShell*;** fortunately, the **problem has been fixed in PowerShell *Core***, fortunately.
  - In the case at hand, given that `$Folder` contains a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` *object* as returned by `Get-ChildItem`, `$Folder.FullName` is simplest (but constructing the path by prepending `$TargetPath` works too).
  - In Windows PowerShell, **even though `$Folder` is a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` object that does contain the full path information**, when converted to a *string* it ***situationally* may only expand to its mere directory *name* (last path component) - it depends on how the `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` and `[System.IO.FileInfo]`instances were obtained, namely:

    If `Get-ChildItem` was called either *without a path argument* or via a path argument that is a *directory*, the output objects stringify to their mere file/directory name** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details.
    Simple example: `$d = (Get-ChildItem -Directory $HOME)[0]; "$d"` yields `Contacts`, for instance, not `C:\Users\jdoe\Contacts`.

    - By contrast, if you pass such objects via the *pipeline* to `Remove-Item`, PowerShell does use the full path.
  - **Important**: If you do pass the target folder as a *parameter* and neglect to specify the full path *while not in the same location as the target folder*, the name may therefore interpreted as relative to the *current* location, and you'll either get a `Cannot find path` error - as you saw - or, even worse, you may end up deleting a *different* folder by the same name if one happens to be present in your current location (directory).

As stated, you can avoid the full-path problem by *piping* the folder objects returned by `Get-ChildItem` to `Remove-Item`, which also enables a more elegant, single-pipeline solution (PSv3+):

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\Folder"
$Days = 5
Get-ChildItem -Directory $TargetFolder |  
  Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$Days) | 
    Remove-Item -WhatIf -Force -Recurse
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` to perform actual removal.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing remove-item on the full path, e.g.

```
    $TargetFolder = "C:\Folder\"
    $Folders = get-childitem -path $TargetFolder

    foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
    {
      remove-item $TargetFolder$Folder -recurse -force
    }
```

Comment: That works, but using `$Folder.FullName` is simpler.