# Find specific files by date modified and copy to the relevant folder

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a PowerShell script which can find the files (`N30008xx.txt`, `N30005xx.txt`) from the source directory and copy them to the destination directory by creating a folder with the same name of the file's modification date.

I'm able to run the below script which creates the folder by files modified date.

```
$p = "Filesourcepath"

Get-ChildItem -Path $p |
    Where-Object { ! ($_.PSIsContainer) } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $newDir = Join-Path $p ($_.LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        New-Item -Path $newDir -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $newDir
    }
```

Comment: If you want to **copy** somthing you shouldn't **move** it.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code *should* work in principle**.
(As of this writing, there's confusion over *copying* vs. *moving*, and the aspect of matching only select files is missing.)

Below is a **streamlined version of your code**, which however, **does *not* explain your symptom** - you need to provide more information for us to diagnose your problem.

---

The streamlined code below:

- takes advantage of the PSv3+ `-File` `Get-ChildItem` parameter to limit matching to *files* (as opposed to *directories*) - this saves the need for `Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer }`.
- uses `-LiteralPath` to pass the literal `$dir` path; while `-Path` (which is also the positional default) often works fine too, it's important to note that it interprets is argument as a *wildcard expression*, which can have unexpected results).
- uses `-Filter` to provide the file mask (wildcard expression); this is generally preferable to using the `-Path` parameter, because it filters at the source (Windows API call) and is therefore faster, which can make a noticeable difference when processing large directories.
  *Caveat*: the wildcard language supported in the `-Filter` argument is *more limited* than PowerShell's and also burdened with legacy quirks; in short: sticking with `*` and `?` should be fine; for the full story, see [this well-researched answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375).
- uses `-Force` instead of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` in order to either create a directory or use a preexisting one.

  - Note that `New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force` returns a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instance in *both* scenarios (either the newly created directory or the preexisting one), which the code takes advantage of.

```
# Create sample dir. with 2 sample files in it.
$tmpDir = New-Item -Force -Type Directory tmpDir
New-Item -Type File -Force -Path ('N30008xx.txt', 'N30005xx.txt' -replace '^', "$($tmpDir.FullName)/")

$dir = $tmpDir
$fileMask = 'N*.txt'

Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath $dir -Filter $fileMask | ForEach-Object {
  $newDir = Join-Path $dir $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
  $_ | Move-Item -Destination (New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force $newDir) 
}
```

**Caveat re generalization** of this code:

- You're creating the target subdirectories inside the *source* directory.
- If you were to use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to process the source directory *recursively*, you'd end up processing matching files *twice*: first when moving them, and then again when finding them in their moved-to location.
  (In this particular case this would only cause an *inefficiency*, however, because processing the already-moved files attempts to move them into the directory where they already are, which is a quiet no-op.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your PowerShell that should work.

Note: Your destination directory cannot be located under the source directory otherwise you will have a forever recursive move.

```
$p = pwd
$dst = "c:/tmp/testdir"

Get-ChildItem -Path $p | Where-Object  {
    $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false
} | ForEach-Object {
    $newdir = Join-Path -Path $dst -ChildPath ($_.LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $newdir)) {
        Write-Host "Create directory $newdir"
        New-Item -Path $newdir -ItemType Directory
    }
    Write-Host "Copy file $_"
    Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination $newdir
}
```

Comment: it doesn't copy the files!

Comment: While the warning re creating new files inside a directory being enumerated is worth heeding in general, there is _no_ problem in this case, because `-Recurse` is not being used. Careful with `Move-Item -Path $_`: it will (regrettably) only work if `$p` also happens to be the current location, because `$_` is effectively bound by _filename only_; either use `$_.FullName` or use the pipeline - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40494173/45375) of mine (As an aside: better to use `-LiteralPath`).